# .parent() и поиск разных родителей

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Делаю проверку на валидность формы. Сделал так:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    if (!$(this)[0].checkValidity()){
        $(this).parent('.form-group').removeClass('has-sucess');
        $(this).parent('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $(this).parent('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
    }
});
```

Но у меня у одних полей родитель `.form-group`, а у других `.input-group`:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="login-pass" placeholder="Пароль" pattern="[A-z0-9]{6,15}" title="Мінімальна кількість символів - 6.">
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
     <label for="register2">Прізвище</label>
     <input name="register-surname" type="text" class="form-control" id="register2" placeholder="Ваше прізвище" pattern="^[А-ЯІЇ][а-яії]{2,9}" title="інімальна кількість символів - 3. Перша велика." required>
</div>
```

Как мне сделать поиск `.parent()` по нескольким параметрам?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понял, вы меняете родителю классы, чтобы показать пользователю, правильно ли заполнено поле. Поэтому думаю, что в обоих примерах вам надо искать именно `form-group`. Тогда вы будете добавлять классы к блокам одного и того же уровня и с одинаковым «базовым» классом. Так будет меньше проблем с настройкой стилей.

Попробуйте метод [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/). Он найдёт ближайшего предка с нужным вам классом.

А метод [.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) поможет сократить код. Например, так:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
   var isValid = $(this)[0].checkValidity();
   $(this).closest('.form-group').toggleClass('has-success', isValid).toggleClass('has-error', !isValid);
});
```

```css
.has-success { background: green; }
.has-error { background: red; }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" name="login-pass" placeholder="Пароль" pattern="[A-z0-9]{6,15}" title="Мінімальна кількість символів - 6.">
     </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
     <label for="register2">Прізвище</label>
     <input name="register-surname" type="text" class="form-control" id="register2" placeholder="Ваше прізвище" pattern="^[А-ЯІЇ][а-яії]{2,9}" title="інімальна кількість символів - 3. Перша велика." required>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Как я могу более корректно это сделать?

Comment: @Cactus Добавил пример кода.

Comment: То, что надо. Спасибо! :)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `.closest()`:

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
  var formgroup = $(this).closest('.form-group');
  if (!$(this)[0].checkValidity()) {
    formgroup.removeClass('has-sucess');
    formgroup.addClass('has-error');
  } else {
    formgroup.removeClass('has-error');
    formgroup.addClass('has-success');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А как мне сделать еще не только для `.form-group` но и для `.input-group`? В плане того, чтобы меньше кода писать :)